# java - create instances of objects from abstract class

Tags: java, android, oop

I have an abstract Record class that represents database records which has two abstract methods: getTable() and getColumns(). I then have a Customer class that extends Record and i implement those abstract methods in this class.

I'm trying to figure out how i can get a list of all Customers but keep the method as reusable as possible so i'd prefer a getAllRecords(Record record) method than getAllCustomers() method.

Here's what i have thus far. I can't create a new Record() object because it's abstract and need to create an instance of the class that was passed in.

```
//i'd like to do something like this to get all of the Customers in the db 
// datasource.getAllRecords(new Customer());

public List<Record> getAllRecords(Record record) {
    List<Record> records = new ArrayList<Record>();

    Cursor cursor = database.query(record.getTable(),
        record.getColumns(), null, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
      Record record = cursorToRecord(cursor, record);
      records.add(record);
      cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    // Make sure to close the cursor
    cursor.close();
    return records;
  }

  private Record cursorToRecord(Cursor cursor, Record record) {


    Record record = new Record(); <-- somehow clone a new instance of the record that was passed in

    record.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
    record.setValue("aKey",cursor.getString(1));
    return record;
  }
```

would having some kind of RecordRegistry object make sense instead of having individual factory classes for each subclass of Record?

```
class RecordRegistry{

    private static final List<Record> RECORDS;

    static {
            final List<Record> records = new ArrayList<Record>();
            records.add(new Customer());
            records.add(new Company());

            RECORDS = Collections.unmodifiableList(records);
    }

    public List<Record> allRecords(){

        return RECORDS;
    }

    public Record buildRecord(Class cClass){

        String className = cClass.getName().toString();

        if(className.equalsIgnoreCase("customer")){
            return new Customer();
        }else if(className.equalsIgnoreCase("company")){
            return new Company();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there any children of the Record class that can be instantiated?

Comment: Customer is a class that extends Record and can be instantiated, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the class of the `Record`, provided that all the subclasses of `Record` will have a no-arg constructor.

```
Record newRecord = record.getClass().newInstance();
```

Note that you can just pass the class instead of the object itself.

You can also pass a factory that will be responsible to instanciate the right class.

```
interface RecordFactory {
    Record create();
}

class CustomerFactory implements RecordFactory {
    Record create() {
        return new Customer();
    }
}

public List<Record> getAllRecords(RecordFactory factory) {
    ...
    for(...) {
        ...
        Record record = factory.create();
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: @David As noted in the question, this is a brittle design that would fail at runtime if a no-arg constructor was missing. I would urge you consider whether this approach is really what you want to do. It doesn't feel very "Java".

Comment: Oooh i guess i didn't understand. In my subclass i need to have an empty construct method? Do you have a more "Java" approach idea?

Comment: @David The factory approach is more "Java". I added an example.

Comment: so i would need to write several individual factory classes for each class that extends my Record class? is that the idea?

Comment: @David one factory class for each `Record` subclass

Comment: I edited my original question with an idea i had. What do you think of that?

Comment: @David your new idea is not a lot more "Java" than using `newInstance()`

Comment: @WilQu alight. I guess i'll go with the factory pattern. I was trying to avoid creating more classes but it makes the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

An odd use case. I would make the `cursorToRecord` method abstract. That pushes the logic into each class, which knows how to build itself from a `Cursor`.

```
public abstract Record cursorToRecord(Cursor cursor, Record record);
```

Comment: yeah i thought about doing that. Seems kind of messy though

Comment: @David On reflection, my original suggestions were a bit naff. See edit above.

Comment: hmmm i'd like to keep my models as data source agnostic as possible

Comment: @David But surely each new subclass will introduce additional columns etc. How can one method construct different objects without knowing this information?

Comment: i guess you have a point. I have static final variables that define the table and columns in the classes that extend Record. I guess i'm telling myself that the "columns" could just represent key/value pairs that should be submitted to the datasource(be it database or API) and the "table" is the resource i'm using

Answer (score 0):

Not directly answering your Q, but take a look at the Android guides on Content Providers ( https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html).  They allow for flexible data access amongst other benefits.  I found them worth the initial learning and setup effort (especially when used w/ Loaders)

Answer (score 0):

What about reflection?

```
Record newRecord = record.getClass().newInstance();
```